# How to put an image on UIActionSheet?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uiactionsheet

How to put image on `UIActionSheet` on right position of text. Like given in apple music player.

[image]

Note: Don't answer with custom view, if it is possible in `UIActionSheet`, Kindly let us know.

Comment: There is no public API for this with UIAlertController. Despite your request, you need to use a custom alert that supports this feature.

Comment: Just FYI, UIActionSheet is depreciated since iOS 8.

Answer (score 2):

> Don't answer with custom view

Then you are effectively forbidding anyone to answer, because *that is what you do*.

First of all, there is no such thing as UIActionSheet. It was deprecated four years ago. Today we use UIAlertController.

UIAlertController is nothing but a prepackaged presented view controller. It does *nothing* that you could not do for yourself. It is also deliberately very simple and limited. So if you want to do something that goes beyond the limits what UIAlertController gives you, then you simply create a custom presented view controller. Adding the animation and "dimming view" to make it look like a standard action sheet is easy; just make a custom transition animation.

That is what the interface shown in your screen shot is. It is *not* a UIActionSheet. It is *not* a UIAlertController. It's just a custom presented view controller that Apple has created. And so can you.

Comment: yes @matt, perhaps  you are right.. I thought I don't know the way, if somebody else know about it, so I posted that question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, you _don't_ know the way; that is why you should not, in your question, forbid people from telling you the way.

Comment: @matt is right, it's pretty custom.  Do a search for libraries.  There are plenty of good ones out there that might save you time from building something from scratch.  Here are a couple worth mentioning.  https://github.com/CooperRS/RMActionController and https://github.com/dillidon/alerts-and-pickers